# suppress repeated values in a column in a data.frame in r

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I have a simple data.frame

```
mydf <- read.csv("mydf.csv")
mydf

                         SOC        Preferred.Term       Serious       Non.Serious
           cardiac disorders             dizziness             0                 0
           cardiac disorders    dizziness postural             0                 1
           cardiac disorders          palpitations             0                 0
           cardiac disorders              dyspnoea             0                 1
           cardiac disorders     oedema peripheral             0                 0
               eye disorders lacrimation increased             0                 3
               eye disorders              eye pain             0                 0
               eye disorders             mydriasis             0                 0
               eye disorders        vision blurred             0                 0
               eye disorders     visual impairment             0                 1
              oral disorders         dental caries             0                 0
              oral disorders        tooth fracture             0                 0
```

You can see that the column titled SOC has several repeats.
I want to present this as a table where I only show the 1st instance of any unique term in the SOC column. 
In other words, I want the table to look like this:

```
                         SOC        Preferred.Term       Serious       Non.Serious
           cardiac disorders             dizziness             0                 0
                                dizziness postural             0                 1
                                      palpitations             0                 0
                                          dyspnoea             0                 1
                                 oedema peripheral             0                 0
               eye disorders lacrimation increased             0                 3
                                          eye pain             0                 0
                                         mydriasis             0                 0
                                    vision blurred             0                 0
                                 visual impairment             0                 1
              oral disorders         dental caries             0                 0
                                    tooth fracture             0                 0
```

Is there a simple/quick way to modify my data.frame to remove the repeats in the 1st column?

Alternatively, is there some type of presentation package in R that will make a table that will eliminate the repeated terms in the 1st column?

Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way that assumes the variable `SOC` is sorted and is of class character:

```
mydf$SOC[duplicated(mydf$SOC)] <- ""
```

Comment: That's awesome. Thank you!